# .htaccess in wordpress site issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Google's WMT tools is seeing my site as 2 different sites so I want to implement a 301 redirect from non www to www. The main site www.mysite.com is built using Flash and a folder that contains the wordpress blog is held seperatly in www.mysite.com/blog/.

In the Wordpress folder there is a .htaccess file with the following script which doesn't look right as there are 2 RewriteRules and RewriteCond entries. Should I remove 1 of them or are they both needed?

Why is !-f and !-d in there - what do they do?

Also should my main Flash site have its own .htaccess file for the 301 non-www to www?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

#If the file requested is index.php from the current folder(here: blog)
#do not do anything
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

#if other requests are not regular files or directories,
#redirect it to /blog/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Do not remove any of the above rules. They are fine & required. In fact, I would suggest you to add this as well:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

From [rewritecond <sup>apache docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) :
`-f`, `-d` & `-l` are variants of CondPatterns. Instead of real regular expression strings.

> - '-d' (is directory)
>     Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a directory.
> - '-f' (is regular file)
>     Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a regular file.
> - '-l' (is symbolic link)
>     Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a symbolic link.

if prefixed by an exclamation mark ('!') it leads to negate their meaning. i.e. `!-f` means is not a regular file.

---

For redirecting from `non www` to `www` urls use this in your `.htaccess` in your `DocumentRoot`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

- [flag_nc(nocase) <sup>apache docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc)
- [flag_l(last) <sup>apache docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)
- [flag_r(redirect) <sup>apache docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r)
- `R=301` is for permanent redirect

Comment: Thanks for explaining these! Just to be clear are you saying that I should use 2 x .htaccess files - one in each of the root folders?

Comment: @ubique yes. but use the one you have in the blog folder. And the one I have written in your documentroot.